# How to enable SSL on Tomcat8 in Ubuntu with cert/key file

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, tomcat8

How can I enable SSL for Tomcat using a pair of crt/key file?

I tried this:

I enabled the APR connector in server.xml configuration:

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                 maxThreads="150"
                 enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                 acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
                 SSLEnabled="true"
                 SSLCertificateFile="my.crt"
                 SSLCertificateKeyFile="my.key" />
```

I had to use APR instead of Http11NioProtocol because crt and key file are updated/renewed automatically by an external process. And seems that Http11NioProtocol can use only keystore.

Then I tried to install APR:

```
sudo apt-get install libapr1 libapr1-dev
```

I reloaded Tomcat, but APR is not found:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libapr1` is a prerequesit for using APR but it's simply not enough. You need to install package `libtcnative-1`.

`libapr1` is normally installed as a dependency thereof. You might flag it afterwards as not manually installed. You can do this with the command `apt-mark auto libapr1`.

There is one additional line in the configuration (`server.xml`) that needs to be active: `<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />`. This loads the native libraries.

Comment: I tried to install libctnative-1 and I got: `libtcnative-1 is already the newest version (1.1.33-1)`. Then I tried to restart tomcat but I got: `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available` from tomcat log.

Comment: The standard config contains the line `<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />`. Did you leave it in place?

Comment: This is the problem! That listener was commented in the standard config, uncommenting it I solved.Please add it to your solution so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Tobia I edited the answer. I obviously was wrong in the assumption that it's active by default.